# A conjecture related to two conic-sections intrinsically bound to any triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, conic-sections

Given any triangle $\triangle ABC$, let consider two sides, e.g. $AC$ and $BC$.

We draw two ellipses, one with foci in $A,C$ passing by $B$, and the other one with foci in $B,C$ and passing by $A$,  obtaining two points $D$ and $E$ where the two ellipses intersect.

[image]

Now, we draw two straight lines, one passing by $A$ and $C$ and the other passing $B$, $C$, annotating the intersection points $F,G,H,I,J,K$ with the two ellipses.

[image]

My conjecture is that

> **Given any triangle $\triangle ABC$, the six points $F,H,D,G,I,E$ and the six points $A,J,D,K,B,E$ always determine two conic-sections.**

[image]

[image]

NOTE: This conjecture is inspired by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2840491/559615) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2842577/559615), although I was not able so far to use the tools suggested therein to prove it.

Thanks for any suggestion for a compact proof!

Comment: My first idea would be to use the [Braikenridge-Maclaurin theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braikenridge%E2%80%93Maclaurin_theorem), which is the converse of [Pascal's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_theorem#Related_results).

Comment: @Servaes Thanks for your reference. I read them!

Comment: This recalls me https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/GeoGebra/StarElementary.shtml

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thanks. I will have a look!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conjecture is true and can be proved as follows.

Consider the conics $\Gamma=DHFEBK$, $\Gamma'=DJAEIG$ and $\Psi=DHFEJ$.
We have to prove that $G\in\Psi$.

Since $C$ is a common focus of $\Gamma$ and $\Gamma'$, they corrensponds under the homology $\Lambda$ of center $C$ and axis $DE$ sending $B$ into $J$.
Consequently, we have $\Lambda(K)=G$.

In the conics $\Gamma$ and $\Psi$ consider, respectively, the hexagons $DEFKBH$ and $DEFG'JH$ where $G'$ is the intersection of $\Psi$ with $AC$ other than $F$.
Then by Pascal's Theorem the lines $KB$ and $G'J$ meets on $DE$.
Consequently, $G'$ must to be the image of $K$ under $\Lambda$, hence
$$G'=\Lambda(K)=G$$
which concludes the proof.