# A basic relation intrinsic to any (non-isosceles) triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, geometric-construction

Given any non-isosceles triangle  $ABC$, let denote with $AB$ its longest sides, and draw the two circles with centers in $A$ and $B$ and passing by $C$. They determine two additional points $E$ and $D$ on the side $AB$.

[image]

If we draw the circles with centers in $A$ and $B$ and passing by $D$ and $E$, respectively, we obtain two other points $F$ and $G$ on the sides $AC$ and $CB$, respectively.

[image]

The whole triangle results subdivided in three kinds of segments of lenght $\alpha$ (red), $\beta$ (blue) and $\gamma$ (green).

[image]

(In this post [A conjecture related to a circle intrinsically bound to any triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2840491/559615) is shown that the points $DFCGE$ always determine a circle).

Given the lengths of the three sides of $ABC$, ($\overline{AB}=\alpha+\beta+\gamma$, $\overline{AC}=\alpha+\gamma$, and $\overline{CB}=\beta+\gamma$), the triangle $ABC$ is uniquely determined.

> **What is the general relation between $\alpha,\beta$ and $\gamma$?**

So far, I observed that $\gamma=\sqrt{2\alpha\beta}$ for each right triangle, but I have troubles to find the function $\gamma=\gamma(\alpha,\beta)$ for a general triangle.

Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There exists no general relation independent of $\,a,b,c\,$, unless there are additional known conditions on $\,a,b,c\,$. The equations resolve to:

$$
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
\alpha = c - a \\
\beta = c - b \\
\gamma = a+b-c
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$

If you know nothing else about $\,a,b,c\,$ then about all you can say is that $\,\alpha,\beta,\gamma \ge 0\,$.

But if you know that for example $\,c^2=a^2+b^2\,$ (i.e. $\,\triangle ABC\,$ is a right triangle) then you can indeed derive $\,\gamma^2=2 \alpha\beta\,$, which is the relation you found.

Comment: You mean that such function can be found given an angle, e.g. given $A\hat{C}B$?

Comment: @andrea.prunotto Yes, just write the law of cosines for the known angle and substitute $\,a,b,c\,$ in terms of $\,\alpha,\beta,\gamma\,$, then you get a relation between $\,\alpha,\beta,\gamma\,$ and $\,\cos C\,$.

Comment: I see. But if I give the three sides, and I know that one is the longest one, I should already know everything about the triangle. And since $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are uniquely defined, shouldn't this been enough? I mean, if $ABC$ is not a right triangle, then it cannot possibly be that $\gamma^2=2\alpha\beta$... Sorry if I am a bit confusing!

Comment: @andrea.prunotto `shouldn't this been enough` Enough for what? It *is* enough to calculate $\,\alpha,\beta,\gamma\,$ in terms of $\,a,b,c\,$, see the formulas above. It is *not* enough to calculate $\,\gamma\,$ in terms of $\,\alpha,\beta\,$, though. Or, think at it the other way around: if it were possible to find $\,\gamma=\gamma(\alpha,\beta)\,$ you could then determine all three of $\,a,b,c\,$ from $\,\beta,\gamma\,$ alone, but of course you can't (unless you use some additional condition).

Comment: I see. One should give an additional information, such as one angle. But it seems to me that the law of cosine yields to awfully complex formulation, isn't it? Do you think that there is a simpler way to write such function $\gamma=\gamma(\alpha,\beta,\text{something else})$ to make the things easier?

Comment: @andrea.prunotto The law of cosines gives something like $\,(1 - 2 \cos C)\gamma^2$ $- 2(\alpha+\beta) \cos C \,\gamma$ $-2\alpha\beta(1+ \cos C)=0\,$ (which of course reduces to $\gamma^2-2\alpha\beta=0$ when $\,\cos C = 0\,$). While not too pretty, it's still just a quadratic in $\,\gamma\,$.

Comment: You're right. I will think about it. But thanks for your explanations: They are really helpful!