# A Robbins Pentagon bound to any (non-isosceles) Integer Triangle?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, polygons, geometric-construction

Given any non-isosceles triangle $\triangle ABC$, and denoting $AB$ its longest side, the following construction
[image]

determines the points $DFGE$ (see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2840491/559615) for details).

> **My conjecture is that if $\triangle ABC$ is an [integer triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_triangle), then the pentagon $DFCGE$ is a [Robbins pentagon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robbins_pentagon), and viceversa**.

[image]

I am not sure of this claim. Therefore, I ask your advice both to assess if this is true and, otherwise,

> **to find the supplementary conditions needed.**

Thanks for your help!

Comment: In a $3,4,5$ triangle where $AD=AF=2$ we get $DF=\sqrt{8/5}$, so the conjecture is false. There needs to be, at least, a condition that will force $DF$ and $EG$ to be rational.

Comment: @nickgard Thanks!!! Please, can you sketch me how you got $DF=\sqrt{8/5}$?

Comment: OK, I see it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, let $AD=x=2$ and $EB=z=1$ and $DE = y=2$. Then

$$\begin{eqnarray}c=x+y+z &=& 5\\
b=x+y &=& 4\\
a=y+z &=& 3\end{eqnarray}$$

Now, $$ \cos \alpha = {b^2+c^2-a^2\over 2bc} = {4\over 5}\in\mathbb{Q}$$ so $$DF^2 = 2x^2-2x^2\cos \alpha  = x^2{2\over 5}\implies DF\notin \mathbb{Q}$$

Comment: True, but if $AD=EB$ then $\triangle ABC$ is isosceles, isn't it?

Comment: But I'm almost sure if you play a little with $x,y,z$ you will get negative result.

Comment: Yes. I also believe it. But then, which other  conditions may be needed to make the conjecture true?

Comment: I edited also the title of the post, this way there's less confusion.

Comment: Thanks. As @nickgard said in the comments, we would need also $DF$ and $GE$ to be rational. I wonder which class of integer triangles satisfies such request, I mean if we can structure such class better than saying "$DF$, $GE$ are rational"...

Comment: I think that additional question is better to put as another question.

Comment: I see. Thanks however for your work here!

Comment: Anyway, obviously $1-\cos \alpha$, $1-\cos \beta$ and $1-\cos \gamma$ sould be squares of rational numbers