# Locus of a vertex defining a circle intrinsic to a triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles, conic-sections

Given a triangle $\triangle ABC$, we draw the circles with centers in two vertices (say, $A,C$ in the picture below) and passing through the third one (say, $B$), determining the points $D$ and $E$ on the side $\overline{AC}$.

[image]

Then, we can draw the two circles with centers in the same two vertices and passing by the $D$ and $E$, determining other two points $F$ and $G$ on the other two sides.

[image]

The five points $B,D,E,F,G$, as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2840491/559615), always determine a circle (red).

[image]

My question is:

> **Given two vertices of $\triangle ABC$, what is the locus determined by the third point in such a way that the red circumference is well defined?**

My suspect is that this locus is the inner part of an ellipse (orange, in the picture below) passing through the two initial vertices, and two points $H,I$ located at the far vertices of two equilateral triangles built on the side defined by the two initial points, as illustrated here:

[image]

But I have difficulties to determine a fifth point $J$ which would define such an ellipse without any ambiguity.

Thanks for your help, and sorry in case of trivialities!

Comment: Since the roles of the points with respect to the circle are different, you should specify which "two vertices of $\triangle ABC$" you intend to keep fixed. Also, to be clear: When you write "the red circumference is well defined", do you mean that the red circle is also fixed in place?

Comment: @Blue You're right. I will edit it. Thanks! About the red circle, I mean that all the $5$ points $B,D,E,F,G$  (or are at least $3$ of them) are defined. Or, is there a  a better way to phrase it? Sorry for confusion.

Comment: For $\triangle ABC$, pt $B$ is defined by fiat; $D$ and $E$ are always constructible on *extended* side $\overleftrightarrow{AC}$. Correspondingly, $F$ and $G$ are constructible on extended sides $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$ and $\overleftrightarrow{BC}$. Thus, there's always a circle through those five pts. I guess you want to confine $D$, $E$, $F$, $G$ to the non-extended *segments*. For $D$ and $E$ that's easy: just require $|AB|$ and $|BC|$ to be less than $|AC|$. (@Edward's football.) Then, $|AF|=|AD|=|AC|-|BC|<|AB|$ (by the Triangle Inequality), so $F$ is automatically okay; likewise, $G$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: When is 5-point circle defined (10/31/18)?]

According to GeoGebra, if $A$ and $C$ are the fixed vertices, the equilateral triangles are significant, but the figure within which circle $BFDEG$ is defined is not an ellipse but rather the figure $HAIC$ (reminiscent of Euclid *Elements I, 1*), that is, the football-shaped overlap of two circles with centers $A$, $C$ and intersections $H$, $I$.

Circle $BFDEG$ persists wherever $B$ is moved within that figure, but shrinks to a point when $\triangle ABC$ degenerates to a line (when $B$ lies on $AC$), and disappears altogether when $B$ is moved outside the figure.

**addendum**: As noted in response(s) to OP's July posting, a necessary condition of the five-point circle $BFDEG$, where $A$, $C$ are fixed, is that $\angle BAC$ and $\angle BCA$ are both acute.  A *further* necessary condition seems to be that neither $BA$ nor $BC$ is greater than the given line $AC$. E.g. if $AB>AC$, then $E$ lies on $AC$ extended and $GBDE$ is no longer an isosceles trapezoid and/or inscribable in the same circle as isosceles trapezoid $FBED$ (cf. @dan fulea response to the July posting).

I note, however, that $G'BDE$ *is* an isosceles trapezoid concyclic with $FBED$, if $G'$ is diametrically opposite $G$ on the circle about $C$, i.e. on side $BC$ extended. But setting this aside as part of a more general problem, we seem to be left with the football.

Comment: +1 It is an interesting observation! Thanks! How can we prove it?